# Flash CS4 Reference for Video Components

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, flash-cs4

I am trying to find a reference for the Video Components that come with flash.  I have added them to a MovieClip and I want to control them, but I cannot find *any* documentation on these classes.

PlayButton, PauseButton, SeekBar, VolumeBar, MuteButton, etc.

These are components that I assume are part of `fl.video`, but there is no reference in the [Flash Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/).

It appears there is some additional classes added to these library objects, as I see a Linkage set for each of these items to their respective classes.  Where can I find information on what methods and properties are available for me to change?

Or even better, is there source code somewhere where I can see exactly what functionality is being added to these items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those components aren't actually components as such - they are just dumb "skins" that have code injected into them by the FLVPlayback component. If you check out the docs for FLVPlayback you'll see that all of the components are just Sprites.

To do what you want you'll just want to dig into the docs for FLVComponent:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html

Hope that helps!